# Display a MDX dimension memeber as a measure (SSAS)

Tags: scope, mdx, olap, cube, measure

I`m relatively new to MDX and any help would be much appreciated
I have a fact table containing information about items: Feature_Parent, Feature and User story. The Feature Parent is the Parent of the Feature and the Feature is the parent of the User Story, it looks something like this:
[image]

And as seen in the table it also contains info about the states of these items
This fact table also has numerical values and this table is connected to a similar dimension table
I also build the following user hierarchy:
[image]

I`ve managed to create the following pivot using Scopes in MDX (The Row labels are the Relationship hierarchy):
[image]

I want to be able to add the State for each item as one column (meaning, add the State column as the Measure in the above pivot), so it would display state for each item for each level
Can someone maybe help me in this?

This is the attribute hierarchy for the States (this is an example for Feature, and I have similar ones for Feature_Parent and User Story):

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: You already have a state in the dimension hierarchy, why not just slice by state? It is not a member but a dimension. The visualisation in the pivot then can be changed in the reporting tool

Comment: Yes, you are right, I`ve managed to do it both ways. Thanks.